# Can I bulk-remove links from a pdf from the command line?

Tags: bash, shell, pdf, uri, qpdf

I'm downloading some newspapers as pdf (for posterity). One title is a pain, it includes URI links in the pdf itself, if you accidentally click these it opens a browser tab to a page that 500s. It's not so bad on a desktop computer, but a pain in the butt if someone is reading it with a tablet. Each issues has approximately 200 of these links.

For a different title, it was as simple as using QPDF, like so:

```
qpdf --qdf --object-streams=disable file temp-file
```

This puts the temp version into postscript mode or something, and I was able to nuke the links with something like this:

```
s/obj\n<<\n(  \/A <<\n    \/S \/URI.+?)>>\nendobj/"obj\n<<\n" . " " x length($1). ">>\nendobj"/sge
```

This still works. However, a 15 meg original pdf is now becoming a 108meg "fixed" pdf. I can accept some bloat, but 720% is a bit absurd (I think it was more like 10% on the other title). Whenever I google for how to do this, I get results for Acrobat Reader and how you can click around in 20 menus to do such... does no one that uses Adobe products ever want to automate this stuff? There are between 180 and 300 links in a typical issue, spread across 45-150 pages (Sunday editions).

Are there any tools that can do this? Are there any clever arguments to qpdf that will make this more reasonable?

PS Yes I know it's hacky as hell to just overwrite the URIs with spaces, but I've never managed to figure out how to remove the objects entirely since their references also have to be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the community edition of cpdf: https://community.coherentpdf.com/

To remove all links in a PDF (well, to replace them with an empty link):

```
cpdf -replace-dict-entry /URI cpdfmanual.pdf -replace-dict-entry-value '""' -o out.pdf
```

This does not remove the annotations - it just makes sure that clicking on them won't go anywhere. It leaves the annotation in place, but with an empty link. You could replace with a working URL too, of course:

```
cpdf -replace-dict-entry /URI cpdfmanual.pdf -replace-dict-entry-value '"https://www.google.com/"' -o out.pdf
```

(You can also use `-replace-dict-entry-search` to replace only certain URLs - see the manual.)

Or, if you just want rid of all the annotations (link and non-link):

```
cpdf -remove-annotations in.pdf -o out.pdf
```

Comment: The difficulty with round-tripping annotations is deciding what objects to output to JSON - or you might end up getting the whole file. For the future, I noticed in the ISO standard the following: "In addition, beginning in PDF 1.3, FDF can be used to define a container for annotations that are separate from the PDF document to which they apply.". So FDF files might be a solution. Of course, you can round-trip the whole file through JSON with `-output-json` and `-j` at the moment, which I forgot to mention in my answer - that would be an alternative method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HexaPDF](https://hexapdf.gettalong.org) (you need to have Ruby installed and then use `gem install hexapdf` to install HexaPDF) and the following small script to remove the links:

```rb
require 'hexapdf'

HexaPDF::Document.open(ARGV[0]) do |doc|
  doc.pages.each do |page|
    page.each_annotation.select {|annot| annot[:Subtype] == :Link}.each do |annot|
      page[:Annots].delete(annot)
    end
  end
  doc.write(ARGV[0] + '_processed.pdf', optimize: true)
end
```

Then batch execute the script for all the files you want the links removed.

Note that this will remove *all* links.

Answer (score 2):

Just to round off the options I would suggest the best is potentially a PDF dedicated command line tool such as cpdf answer by [johnwhitington](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599719/10802527) or a dedicated library like iText.

There are several alternative methods touted for batch text editing your using qpdf

> "temp version into postscript mode or something,"

That is a converted pdf into plain old decompressed text/pdf hybrid qdf so you can run sed or similar string editor. Here the primary difference is the upper out.pdf file shows as ***an editable QDF-1.0 version after editing*** so needs conversion to a conventional PDF as seen in the lower part where the stream is binary thus recompressed.

[image]

**1) qpdf**
At end of a bloating edit exercise the idea is ***to reverse back to application/pdf using***

```
fix-qdf file-temp.pdf>out.pdf
```

***to tidy up redirects*** and then

```
qpdf --compress-streams=y out.pdf outfixed.pdf
```

***back to fixed.pdf***

Other cross platform means are using

**2) pdftk**

```
$ pdftk infile.pdf output outfile.pdf uncompress
```

edit with vim or whatever sed scripting method then

```
$ pdftk outfile.pdf output fixedfile.pdf compress
```

**3) mutool**

```
mutool clean -d [options] input.pdf [output.pdf] [pages]
```

-d Decompress streams. This will make the output file larger, but provides easy access for reading and ***editing the contents with a text editor.***
-i Toggle decompression of image streams. Use in conjunction with -d to leave images compressed.
-f Toggle decompression of font streams. Use in conjunction with -d to leave fonts compressed.
-a ASCII Hex encode binary streams. Use in conjunction with -d and -i or -f to ensure that although the images and/or fonts are compressed, the resulting file can still be viewed and edited with a text editor.

Whichever options you use, need to be reversed when recompressing

**NOTE**

Using text editors will potentially corrupt binary fonts and binary images, thus they need monitoring for any corruption in an editor that changes encoding or line feeds. This pdftk sample shows the image stream has been decompressed well into simple text but beware any change of End Of Line by editor would break up that stream

[image]
[image]

Additionally when making text edits that are not simple byte wise "find and replace", the xref table can be corrupted too much to be reindexed by recompression, try to overwrite with same number of characters when using a text edit method.

**SIDE NOTE**
EVEN if you remove actions and external hyperlinks actions but the text is present the reader will still provide that exploitable action. Same as here https://google.com but html will highlight usually in blue underline.

[image]
[image]

Hence ensure security is on
[image]